# "The request failed with an empty response." SOAP request error in some system after moving to azure app service from VM.

Tags: wpf, azure, web-services, soap

"The request failed with an empty response." web service SOAP request error in **SOME SYSTEM** after moving to azure app service from Azure VM.

Azure log Stack Trace

at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
 at ................

System OS : Microsoft Windows NT

Application : Outlook plugin (WPF)

Comment: No update. After 6 days we are in same problem.

Answer (score 0):

After we move our web service to Azure app service from VM, we need to modify the endpoint address to be the correct URL in `Web.config`.

We can find the web service endpoint address as below:

[image]

Please check if this endpoint address is correct. It may look like: `https://WebAppname.azurewebsites.net/yourWebService.asmx`

Comment: We added the service as a web reference , So you mean to say we should add the service as service reference while changing  to app service.  Also why its working in some system ?.